# how to fetch result in elasticsearch by mixing two values in a field?

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I want to get a random order of result based on a field with two values. 
My result has a cuisine whose values are "indian" & "international". I want to display result by good mixing of this field's value.

```
{
"query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                "terms": {
                    "meta_groups": [
                        "vegan"
                    ],
                    "minimum_should_match": 1
                }
            }
        ]
    }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "random_score": {
            "seed": 314159265387
          }
        }
      ],
      "score_mode": "multiply"
    }
  }
}
```

The is my result set

```
        {
        "_index": "project",
        "_type": "recipes",
        "_id": "9251",
        "_score": 0.53214025,
        "_source": {
           "title": "Grilled Fish With Corn And Pineapple Salsa Recipe",
           "description": "Marinated fish darnes grilled and served with a delicious salsa of corn, tomatoes and pineapple.",
           "source_name": "Sanjeev Kapoor",
           "cuisine": "indian"
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "project",
        "_type": "recipes",
        "_id": "9235",
        "_score": 0.507389,
        "_source": {
           "title": "Kerela Meen Curry Recipe",
           "description": "Surmai curry - popular Kerela dish",
           "source_name": "Sanjeev Kapoor",
           "cuisine": "indian"
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "foodini",
        "_type": "recipes",
        "_id": "58",
        "_score": 0.4899247,
        "_source": {
           "title": "Magical Blueberry Vanilla Chia Seed Jam",
           "description": "no-description",
           "source_name": "Oh She Glows",
           "cuisine": "international"
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "foodini",
        "_type": "recipes",
        "_id": "147",
        "_score": 0.48571476,
        "_source": {
           "title": "Heather's Toasted Super Seed Power Bread",
           "description": "no-description",
           "source_name": "Oh She Glows",
           "cuisine": "international"
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "foodini",
        "_type": "recipes",
        "_id": "118",
        "_score": 0.4791146,
        "_source": {
           "title": "Easy Tomato Basil Cream Pasta",
           "description": "no-description",
           "source_name": "Swathis kitchen",
           "cuisine": "international"
        }
     }
```

Need to perform some sort of query to get the result with a good mix of indian & international cuisine's. Right now its a sequence of indian and then international cuisine.  Any leads would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution of this problem. We can use Random method and avoid usage of seed. Seed might help when we wan't to bring the pagination into picture. Here is my code

```
{
"from": 15, 
"size": 5, 
"query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                "terms": {
                    "meta_groups": [
                        "vegan"
                    ],
                    "minimum_should_match": 1
                }
            }
        ]
    }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "random_score": {
            "seed": 31415926255

          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
 }
```

This query gives me multiple adavantage

```
1. Random set of result each time I change the seed. 
2. Helps me in having a random order.
3. Easily maintainable pagination.
```